# Android funf framework - Stale Data Exception

Tags: android

So, I started with the WifiScanner tutorial and used the 
funf-0.3.0.jar to use all the builtin probes. However, some of the 
builtin probes (CallLogProbe, SMSProbe, ContactProbe, ImagesProbe, 
VideosProbe, BrowserSearchesProbe, BrowserBookmarksProbe) are throwing 
StaleDataExceptions like this:

```
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): 
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor 
after it has been closed. 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursor ToCursorAdaptor.java: 
75) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.getCount(BulkCursorToCursorAdapt or.java: 
81) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
android.database.AbstractCursor.isLast(AbstractCursor.java:221) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
android.database.CursorWrapper.isLast(CursorWrapper.java:142) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
edu.mit.media.funf.probe.ContentProviderProbe 
$ContentProviderIterator.hasNext(ContentProviderProbe.java:213) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
edu.mit.media.funf.probe.ContentProviderProbe.sendProbeData(ContentProvider Probe.java: 
131) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
edu.mit.media.funf.probe.ContentProviderProbe 
$1.run(ContentProviderProbe.java:86) 
03-09 11:58:34.851: E/AndroidRuntime(14559): at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does anyone have suggestions about why this is happening and how to 
fix it ?